# Can php's session_reset be used to reload a modified session?

Tags: php, session, reload

In [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/196524/117932) from security.SE, a cross-site login scheme was proposed.

In essence, all user info is fist stored on a main application server, and not synchronized with any CDN server. All servers are private and are served only to registered users.

When a client makes media requests from a CDN server, it also first makes an authentication request using a token it got from the application server -- the CDN server creates a session for the client for all of the requests and waits for the originating application server for a positive authentication token predicate before marking the session as authenticated and responding to media requests.

Now a bit on implementation. I'd like to know if the PHP's `session_reset()` function can be used to reload a session that is modified in another request; and if it can, how does it work?

## Note1

The session data are store in default location as configured by the shipped `php.ini`. That is 9/10 probability in `/var`

Comment: Please explain the gist of what's required here so your question makes sense in itself, without requiring another thread on another site to make sense.

Comment: @deceze I've explained what I'd like to know, the first paragraph just explains why I want to know that and serves as a wikilink. Hope this can put the question off hold.

Comment: To be frank, your schema’s explanation is a bit hard to follow, and suddenly jumping from a high level authentication schema explanation to minute details of PHP leaves me with the overall impression that this may be a bad, convoluted idea. But that’s mostly a gut feeling…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[session_reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-reset.php) will just discard changes, which were not yet stored ...

to even use it, you would need to call to [session_write_close()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before.

you probably might rather be looking for [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

and better change the values, as required - in a rather controlled way.

Comment: I've understood the first 2 paragraphs -- session data must be session_write_close()'d before it can be session_reset()'d by others. I think maybe you can add a annoted code snippet explaining step-by-step what will occur by each call? I don't quite understand why we need session_set_cookie_params(), so can you add a few for-examples?

Comment: @DannyNiu `session_set_cookie_params()` just appeared related to me... because CDN tends to have different host-names - and therefore this has to be considered, somehow. you didn't even tell which CDN, therefore this all is quite theoretical (eg. if authentication would even be supported there). also the session storage is unclear... if this is a `MEMORY` table on mySQL, it would instantly change.

Comment: The authentication with CDN and with app server use different cookie, their session names are different, so I didn't consider (to my humble knowledge, or even knew) session_set_cookie_params(). But thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: If one cookie authenticates it all, then I have to somehow come up with a way to share and sync session data, which is actually somewhat more complex then using server-to-server authtoken.